# ImageMagick doesn't convert the file type while resizing

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

This is an extension problem. Say I have a JPEG image with a .png extension. Let's call this file `image.png` (keep in mind it's still internally a real JPEG). When I resize it (and overwrite) with:

```
convert -resize 100x100 image.png image.png
```

what happens is ImageMagick thinks I want to also convert the image to the real PNG format (since it's a JPEG but output file has a .png extension).

Is there any way to resize an image with ImageMagick without converting it to a format specified by the extension of output file? I just want this particular image to stay as a JPEG and without converting it to a real .png (image/png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  convert -resize 100x100 image.png jpg:image.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect it to stdout

```
convert -resize 100x100 image.png -format JPEG - > image.png
```

Comment: Can't work since `image.png` would be truncated by the shell before `convert` is even launched.